# How can I print all of specific attributes in a whole linked struct list when debugging with gdb?

Tags: c, struct, gdb, linked-list, pretty-print

Supposing a linked-list have lots of nodes , and each node is a struct like this

```
struct sth{
    int key;
    struct sth * next;
};
```

How could I print all the "key" values in gdb easily instead of input commands like 
`print (*head).key`,`print (*head->next).key`,`print (*head->next->next).key`...

thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom pretty-printer in Python and plug it into gdb 7.0 or later.  Here's a good-looking tutorial:
http://blog.rethinkdb.com/make-debugging-easier-with-custom-pretty-prin